# Meaning of ^ selector in tabbed nav

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a question about a specific line of code within a tabbed-navigation example I saw.

```css
[id^=tab]:checked + label{}
```

I know the code is saying, in general, if this tab is clicked, do  something.

But does the `^` indicator mean look for anything with the name tab in it?

Comment: List of all CSS3 selectors: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [Attribute Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

`[id^=tab]` Represents an element with an attr name of `id` and whose value is prefixed by "tab".

Answer (score 1):

This selects every element whose id attribute value begins with "tab"

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp